# c language, can't break a loop in a function that fills a shape i defined

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

i was asked to initilize a program with a defined shape and to create a function to fill its,
i chose a triangel and worked out how to fill it, the problem is at the end ,my return function throws me into an endless loop and i have no idea how to get out of it, the function suppose to return a filled array,it indeed dose that but i have no idea how to break the loop at the end.
the function must be recursive.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char Filler(char shape[][9],int start_colume,int start_line)
{
    int i,j,n,m;
    char nshp[5][9];

    for(i=start_line;i<5;i++)//condition for filling the function
    {
        for(j=start_colume;j<9;j++)
        {

            if(shape[i][j]!='*')
            shape[i][j]='|';
            if(shape[i][j]=='*')
                break;
        }
        Filler(shape,(start_colume)-1,(start_line)+1);//recursive rule
    }

    for(n=0;n<5;n++)//copying the created array into another array
    {
        for(m=0;m<9;m++)
            nshp[n][m]=shape[n][m];

    }

    return nshp[5][9];//the endless loop
}




void main ()
{
    char shape[5][9]={{' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',},
                      {' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',},
                      {' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' ',},
                      {' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',},
                      {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',}};
    int i=0,j=0;
    char nshap;
    for(i;i<5;i++)
    {
    for(j;j<9;j++)
      printf("%c",shape[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
    if(j=8)
        j=0;
    }

    nshap = Filler(shape,4,1);
    printf("%c",nshap);
    printf("\n");
}
```

a little idiotic but I'm debugging this function for a hour or so, i tried to use pointers but i'm really bad with it.

Comment: nshp[5][9];//the endless loop, is actually out of bounds. The matrix has 5 rows which are accessed from 0 to 4. Same with columns.

Comment: `if(j=8)` sets j to 8 and always executes the body. You most likely want `if(j == 8)`!

Comment: actually that was the first thing i did but for some reason it returns only the first row of the array

Comment: Milan , what i tried to do at the end is return nshp as a whole arrya of 5 rows and 9 columes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a recursive call to `Filler()` in there but it doesn't look like you actually need it. Do you? What's the recursion termination condition?

Also, the `nshp` local variable doesn't seem too useful because you are copying the `shape` into `nshp`, and then returning a single element from it (using an out of bounds index, as pointed out already).

Comment: no i don't need it but the task ask me specifically to use a recursion, i actually solved it quite fast without using recursion,

Comment: Ok, if it must be recursive then I'm not sure why you've got all those nested loops in there. :)

Comment: probably cause im really bad with c, and only just now starting to learn, found no other way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
In Pseudocode: 

begin main: 

Print data /*your shape*/
Filler (data,0,0);
Print data /* your filled shape*/ 

end main

Filler (data, row, col) {

if row valid then /* in range 0 to 4*/
   Filler (data,row +1,col) /*increment row & recurse */
else if col valid then /* in range 0 .. 8*/
   Filler (data,0,col+1) /*increment col & recurse*/
end if.

if row and col valid then
   if data(row,col) inside your shape then /* a more complex test, look for the star to the left and right of row */
      put fill character in data.
   end if
end if;

}
```